# Use NSPredicate to add up all values

Tags: iphone, core-data, nspredicate

I have a program which uses Core Data. I was kinda cheating when adding the numeric values from each entity in a loop. I read about using NSPredicate to filter the data, but I don't know how to manipulate the data or how the results are even stored. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can do it in two steps, if that fits your requirements.

1. First filter your data with your `NSPredicate` and keep it all in an `NSArray`.
2. Then use a compound operator with Key-Value Coding to get the sum.

Below is an example of how it can be done. To make it self-contained, a hard-coded array is used instead of Core Data:

```
// In reality this array would be the result of a Core Data query:
NSArray *numbers = @[@{@"number":@3},
                     @{@"number":@2}];

NSNumber *sum = [numbers valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.number"];
```

The trick here is the `@sum` compound operator. You can read about it (and another couple of similar operators) [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/CollectionOperators.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use NSExpressionDescription to have Core Data do the summing. I used [this article as a tutorial](http://web.archive.org/web/20110525095716/http://www.aderstedtsoftware.com/users/erik/weblog/4e784/) when I was doing something similar.