# How can I set up an NSPredicate to sum the values of properties inside dictionaries in an array of dictionaries in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate

### Q: How can I set up an *NSPredicate* to sum the values of properties inside dictionaries in an array of dictionaries in iOS?

*Note: answer must be a single string used in a format argument of an NSPredicate object. As in:*
`var pred1:NSPredicate = NSPredicate.init(format: *ANSWER*)`

---

Suppose I have the following dictionary:

```
var ticketState:Dictionary =
[
    "orderTotal":1.2,
    "payments":
    [
        [
            "authCode":"12345",
            "isVoid":"false",
            "amount":1.0
        ],
        [
            "authCode":"54321",
            "isVoid":"false",
            "amount":0.2
        ]
    ],
    "associatedWithReturn":false
]
```

Now I want an `NSPredicate` to check if all the amounts sum up to equal the order total.

Something like:

```
var cond1:String = "sum($payments[].amount == $orderTotal)"
```

Note: I *cannot* use array filtering or a second predicate.

I can access the first payment amount like this:

```
var cond1:String = "$payments[1].amount > 0" //works, returns true
```

This will return true. I just want to check that the sum of all the amounts in payments equals the order Total. This should be a simple operation defined by a single predicate.

How do I write a one-line NSPredicate declaration that accomplishes this?

---

*Note: there is a very specific reason I need it to be a one-line, single NSPredicate initialization format string. But that's an implementation detail; don't worry about it, because someone else might have a different reason than me for needing the same type of initialization.*

Comment: I think you should search before asking http://stackoverflow.com/a/11932302/1403732

Comment: I did search, actually I looked at about 10 different questions and answers before asking. The link you just gave does not directly answer my question — although it does give a good hint, it does not actually show a working NSPredicate that does what I asked. I was able to figure it out from what they said, but you didn't have to downvote my question. Thanks for the tip though, anyway.

Comment: Sorry at first I don't like you question but helped you and second I don't want your votes because of first))

Comment: And man If you post correct answer I will upvote it!

Comment: I posted the correct answer and the code which is the reason why it needed to be one string for NSPredicate. Because GKRule takes NSPredicate as an argument. (Using GKRuleSystem to make business rules.. >D)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var cond1:String = "$payments.@sum.amount == $orderTotal"

var pred1:NSPredicate = NSPredicate.init(format: cond1)
var rule1:GKRule = GKRule.init(predicate: pred1, assertingFact:"completeable", grade:1.0)
var ruleSys:GKRuleSystem = GKRuleSystem.init()

ruleSys.addRule(rule1)
ruleSys.state.addEntriesFromDictionary(ticketState)
ruleSys.evaluate()
print(ruleSys.facts)
```

Returns `["completeable"]`.

Thanks sage444 for the tip that led me to that.

To put it another way:

Swift:

```
var pred1:NSPredicate = 
    NSPredicate.init(format:  "$payments.@sum.amount == $orderTotal")
```

Objective C:

```
NSPredicate *pred1 = 
    [[NSPredicate alloc]initWithFormat:@"$payments.@sum.amount == $orderTotal"];
```

My purpose for this is to initialize an Apple GameplayKit `GKRule` object, which takes an `NSPredicate` object as an argument. However I think it could have many other applications.

Answer (score 1):

This is a native Swift solution which uses to built-in functions

- `map` to put the `amount` values into an array
- `reduce` to add the values

---

```
let payments = ticketState["payments"] as! [[String:AnyObject]]
let amountSum = payments.map{$0["amount"] as! Double}.reduce(0, combine: {$0 + $1})
```

Comment: Just FYI, the answer has to be an NSPredicate to check if all the amounts sum up to equal the order total. (The whole point is because I am making an argument to feed into GKRule, Apple's cool new rule engine they debuted in iOS 9.) But it's nice to see what it would look like not as an NSPredicate, for reference :D

Comment: You didn't mention GKRule in your question… ;-)

Comment: Well, I was trying not to make my question #import unnecessary dependencies :D Most questions about NSPredicate searching nested collections & sets have not mentioned GKRule. I figured it would be best to simply leave it at what the title of the question says. Sorry if the title was not more clear, I know context is important. I will update the original question to reiterate the title itself, which is how it should have been worded, and +1 to you for the answer, which I suspect will help others.

Answer (score 1):

Use following code to get sum

```
var totalAmount:Float = (ticketState.valueForKeyPath("payments.@sum.amount") as! NSNumber).floatValue;
```

Now you can compare it or do anything you want.

For other related operators like average,count etc. you can check other collection operators at following link:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html

Comment: You can cast the result to `Float` directly: `let totalAmount = ticketState.valueForKeyPath("payments.@sum.amount") as! Float` but the collection type must be `NSDictionary`. Swift native collection types don't respond to `valueForKeyPath`

Comment: I apologize, the original question title did not make it clear that I need an NSPredicate object initialization statement. I recognize that the string given in your answer is technically usable as the format argument in such a statement, and I did not make the original question quite explicit enough that was a requirement for a correct answer. +1 however for most of the way there.

Comment: Actually i considered the target.. not way(predicate or KVC).. for any task.. it is not always neccessary that we need to via predicate or KVC.. solution is the only required thing... I have seen your answer.. that is also proper way.. i learned new things from that too.. thanks for that too